# Ngine rewrite language directory

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In my nginx.conf I want to rewrite the URL, except domains contain lang subfolder like this:

> www.domain.com/vi/ or hwww.domain.com/en-us/

if user reaches

> www.domain.com/whatever_not_lang/

then I will return another URL.

I got stuck at the condition `"/vi/"`, I could return another URL, but it will return everything included `/vi/` or `/en-us/`

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to 2 things for different url's on the same host, you create 2 locations, like so:

```
location /en-us/ {
  # do one thing
}

location / {
  # this catches everything else
  # do your rewrite here
}
```

for multiple language codes you can either add multiple locations, or combine all of them as follows:

```
locaton ~* /(en-US|nl-BE|fr-FR)/ {
  # handle the requests with a lang in them, lang being requested is available as
}
```